# About python control motor program error？

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use python to write the program to control the motor, and the error is shown as follows after running:`"message": "No value for argument 'speed_a' in function call pylint(no-value-for-parameter)[93,21]' Below is the code I am using：`

```
import serial
import time
#import threading
import struct
from binascii import unhexlify
from crcmod import mkCrcFun
import binascii
import crcmod

def check_code(byte0, byte1, speed_vel, speed_ang):
    '计算校验码时需要输入的字节'
    read = byte0+byte1+speed_vel+speed_ang  #解析校验码要输入的前几位
    read=(str(binascii.b2a_hex(read))[2:-1])
    print (read)
    return (read)
def crc16_modbus(read):
    '输出的控制电机指令字节码'
    crc16 =crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005,rev=True,initCrc=0xFFFF,xorOut=0x0000)
    data = read.replace(" ","")
    #print (data)
    readcrcout=hex(crc16(unhexlify(data))).upper()
    str_list = list(readcrcout)
    if len(str_list) < 6:
        str_list.insert(2, '0'*(6-len(str_list)))  # 位数不足补0
    crc_data = "".join(str_list)
    #print(crc_data)
    read = read.strip()+crc_data[4:]+crc_data[2:4]
    read = read.encode('UTF-8')
    return read

def motor_speed_vel(speed_v,speed_a):
    '计算小车线速度speed_v'
    DEC1 = speed_v
    DEC2 = speed_a
    byte2 =(struct.pack("i",DEC1)[-4:-3])#线速度
    byte3 =(struct.pack("i",DEC1)[-3:-2])#线速度
    speed_vel = byte2 + byte3
    byte4 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-4:-3])    #角速度两个字节
    byte5 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-3:-2])
    speed_ang = byte4+byte5
    print (speed_vel,speed_ang)
    return (speed_vel,speed_ang)
motor_speed_vel(200,20)
'''
def motor_speed_ang(speed_a):
    '角速度的speed_a的byte码'
    DEC2 = speed_a
    byte4 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-4:-3])    #角速度两个字节
    byte5 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-3:-2])
    speed_ang = byte4+byte5
    print (speed_ang)
    return (speed_ang)
motor_speed_ang(20)
#motor_speed_cal(200,20)  #设定的 （线速度，角速度）
'''

motor_speed_mode = b'\x01\x2F\x60\x60\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0D'
#motor_status = b'\x43\x50\x00\x51\x00\x68\x95'
motor_start = b'\x01\x44\x21\x00\x31\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x75\x34'
motor_stop = b'\x01\x44\x21\x00\x31\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xE5\x34'   # AB轴失能
    
class SpeedMotor:
    def __init__(self, device,speed_v,speed_a):
        # 真实速度
        self.rel_speed = 0
        # 设置的速度
        self.set_speed1 = speed_v
        # 设置角速度
        self.set_speed2 = speed_a
        # 运行状态
        self.run = False
        # 故障状态
        self.fault = None
        # 电机电压
        self.voltage = 0
        # 电机电流
        self.current = 0
        # 设置串口通讯
        self.serial = serial.Serial(device, 115200)
        self.serial.timeout = 0
        # 设置为速度模式
        self.serial.write(motor_speed_mode)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        # 设置加减速度
 #       self.serial.write(b'\x0A\x14\x14\x32')
 #       time.sleep(0.1)
    def motor_speed_set(self):
        '速度设置'
        byte0 = b'\x01'
        byte1 = b'\xEA'
        speed_vel = motor_speed_vel(self.set_speed1)
        speed_ang = motor_speed_vel(self.set_speed2)   
        read = check_code(byte0, byte1, speed_vel, speed_ang)
        speed_code = read
        self.serial.write(speed_code)

    def motor_start(self):
        
        self.serial.write(motor_start)
        self.run = True
    def motor_stop(self):
        
        self.run = False
        self.serial.write(motor_stop)
 
m = SpeedMotor('COM5',200,20)   
m.motor_start()
#for i in range(100):
 #   m.set_speed = i
time.sleep(15)
m.motor_stop()`
```

I don't know if it is because of the problem with my parameter call, or because of the structure of the code, and I am very uncertain about the correctness of the code structure, because I am a beginner.

Comment: Please and the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: All error messages have been added.

Comment: This is a linter message. Is there any problem if you run the program?

Comment: After running the program, the terminal does not report an error, but the motor does not run

Comment: The error you gave is not relevant for starting the motor. I suggest you reduce your code so it does no more than starting the motor and debug the reduce code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to adjust the speed of the motor and adjust the linear and angular speed of the motor for this program. Do you have any good suggestions?